# How can I create objects of a nested class inside the parent class but in another header file?

Tags: c++, class, object, nested

I have a class `Dmx` with a nested class `touchSlider`. So before I had these classes in my `main.cpp` file and just created an object array of `touchSlider` within the `Dmx` class and it worked properly.

How can I implement this here, with different header files? The compiler gives an error message:  `invalid use of incomplete type 'class Dmx::touchSlider'`

The object array is: `touchSlider slider[10] = {50,130,210,290,370,50,130,210,290,370};`

**dmx.h**

```cpp
// dmx.h

#ifndef dmx_h
#define dmx_h

class Dmx {
  public:
    byte number;                                                

    Dmx(byte numberA) {                                                 
      number = numberA;
    }

    void settingsDisplay();
    
    class touchSlider;             // declaration of nested class

    touchSlider slider[10] = {50,130,210,290,370,50,130,210,290,370};  
};

#endif
```

**touchSlider.h**

```cpp
// touchSlider.h

#ifndef touchSlider_h
#define touchSlider_h

#include "dmx.h"

class Dmx::touchSlider{
  private:
  int pos;                                     

  public:
  touchSlider(int posA){                        
    pos = posA;                      
  }

  void printChannel();

};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include "dmx.h"                
#include "touchSlider.h"

Dmx dmx[10] = {Dmx(1), Dmx(2),Dmx(3), Dmx(4), Dmx(5), Dmx(6), Dmx(7), Dmx(8), Dmx(9), Dmx(10)}; 


void Dmx::settingsDisplay() {
    // do something
}

void Dmx::touchSlider::printChannel() {
    // do something
}
```

My previous code (that worked great) where both classes where in the same file looked like this:

```cpp
class Dmx {
  public:
    byte number;                                                

    Dmx(byte numberA) {                                                 
      number = numberA;
    }

    void channelDisplay(){
    }                                            

    void settingsDisplay(){
    }
    
    class touchSlider{
    private:
      int pos;                                     

    public:
      touchSlider(int posA){                        
         pos = posA;                      
      }

      void setChannel(/* some arguments*/){
      }

      void printChannel();
      }
   };             

    touchSlider slider[10] = {50,130,210,290,370,50,130,210,290,370};        
};
Dmx dmx[10] = {Dmx(1), Dmx(2),Dmx(3), Dmx(4), Dmx(5), Dmx(6), Dmx(7), Dmx(8), Dmx(9), Dmx(10)};
```

Comment: Why do you want to implement `Dxm::touchSlider` in a different header file? Why not define it in _dxm.h_ and implement it in _dxm.cpp_ ?

Comment: It is possible to declare touchSlider as being part of Dmx and then define touchSlider outside Dmx, but it is not  possible to then have an array of touchSlider objects within Dmx (a pointer to an array is possible).

Comment: @paolo my thoughts were, that this way it is cleaner. But maybe I am wrong, I assume it would be easier if I have both in the same header file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to create an array:

```
touchSlider slider[10] = {50,130,210,290,370,50,130,210,290,370};
```

You need the class definition available, because the compiler needs to know

1. the size of the struct or class in use and
2. if there's a suitable constructor available.

You now have two options, either you provide the class definition in the header but implement the class within the source file like:

```
// header:

class Dmx
{
public:
    // ...

    class TouchSlider
    {
    public:
        // only DECLARE here:
        TouchSlider(int posA);
        void setChannel(/* some arguments*/);
        void printChannel();
    };
};

// source:

Dmx::TouchSlider::TouchSlider(int posA)
    : pos(posA) // note: prefer the initialiser list!
{ }

void Dmx::TouchSlider::setChannel(/* some arguments*/)
{
}

// ...
```

or you hide away the implementation as you intended, but then you need to allocate the memory *dynamically* (this is the PImpl idiom) – at best with help of a `std::unique_ptr`:

```
class Dmx
{
public:
    // ...
private:
    class TouchSlider; // just declare

    std::unique_ptr<TouchSlider[]> sliders;
};
```

Important (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)), though:

> `std::unique_ptr` may be constructed for an incomplete type T, such as to facilitate the use as a handle in the pImpl idiom. If the default deleter is used, T must be complete at the point in code where the deleter is invoked, which happens in the destructor, move assignment operator, and reset member function of `std::unique_ptr`.

I.e. you cannot implement e.g. your class' destructor in the header file either but need to do so in the source file as well – *after* the nested class' full definition – alike any function that might re-assign another array.

The `std::unique_ptr` avoids necessity of manual memory management (see rules of [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)/[five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782757/rule-of-three-becomes-rule-of-five-with-c11)), on the other hand the class gets non-copiable (but you can work around by providing your own custom copy constructor and assignment while defaulting the move constructor and assignment).

Answer (score 1):

In order to create an array of `touchSlider` the compiler needs a definition of the `touchSlider` class. So as written this will not work.

In the code given

```
touchSlider slider[10] = {50,130,210,290,370,50,130,210,290,370};
```

the complier needs to know how big a `touchSlider` object is so it can allocate enough memory for a `Dmx` object. It also needs to know that a `touchSlider` can be constructed from an `int`. Both these things require the full definition of `touchSlider`.

Now maybe you can use some variation to achieve whatever your goal is, but without more details it's hard to suggest anything.

Comment: so the easiest way would just be to put the nested class and parent class into one header file, am I right? @john

Comment: @LastHerd You have to do a bit more than that. If you want `slider` to be an array then I don't see any alternative to defining `touchSlider` in place.